# I have a list of Objects and I want to sort it by the objects's ID?

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have a list of Objects and I want to sort it by the objects's ID, then all of the information has to be written into a file? [c#]

I don't want the objects to be printed I just want a method which sorts the list so that  I can then invoke the Sort method and use my Serialize class which will put the sorted list into the file.

If you need any other code please let me know.

Thanks In advance.

That's my class which creates a list so that I can put the objects in it.

```
[Serializable]
class ListOfClasses
{

     public List<Classes> fitnessClasses { get; set; }
     public ListOfClasses()
    {
        fitnessClasses = new List<Classes>();  
    }

     public void DeleteClass(Classes c)
     {
         fitnessClasses.Remove(c);
     }

     public void AddClass(Classes c)
     {
         fitnessClasses.Add(c);
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example, assuming the class `Classes` has an `ID` property:

```
fitnessClasses.Sort((a, b) => a.ID.CompareTo(b.ID));
```

Comment: That was fast. :) Furthermore it works :) Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use :

```
fitnessClasses.OrderBy(item => item.ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use any of these methods:

1. Sort using LINQ

   ```
   IEnumerable<Class> sortedClasses = 
       from fitnessClass in fitnessClasses
       orderby fitnessClass.ID
       select fitnessClass;
   ```
2. Sort by using extension methods on System.Linq.Enumerable

   ```
   IEnumerable<Class> sortedClasses = 
       fitnessClasses.OrderBy(fitnessClass => fitnessClass.ID);
   ```
3. Use the Sort method on the List class, which will actually modify the order of the items in the list.

   ```
   fitnessClasses.Sort( 
       (fc1, fc2) => Comparer<int>.Default.Compare(fc1.ID, fc2.ID) );
   ```